# Can't install rpy2 with R 3.1.0

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm very new to python and am trying to install rpy2 (a module to use R commands from python). Currently I have R 3.1.0 installed on mac and python 2.7.2. I got an error saying that "R was not installed as a library". Another user had a similar error and got around it by doing the following:

1. Download newest version of Xcode (4.6.2)
2. In XCode Preferences > Downloads > Install Command line tools
3. Download newest version of R
4. in R-3.0.0 folder: ./configure --enable-R-shlib
5. easy_install rpy2

I upgraded to R 3.1.0 however when I tried to do step 4 from above, I found that R 3.1.0 has different commands to 3.0.0 and enabling shared library use is different.

What I want is a very simple set of instructions to install rpy2 or an equivalent package such that I can use R commands and functions in python. I will happily take direction for any workarounds.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that "--enable-R-shlib" is no longer valid ? (not the case here)

Comment: As @lgautier (who happens to be the author in case you missed it) I am not sure this really changed. I maintain the package for Debian (and hence Ubuntu) and it works for us...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel : Thanks. Working for me as well on Linux, but I am not developing rpy2 on OS X and one never knows (although my bet would be that it did not change).